# Regex: a certain numeral at a certain place

Tags: regex

How can I write a regex expression that checks a certain numeral at a certain place?

For example, if I want to have regex for only numerals, length 7 - I will write
something like

```
^[0-9]{7}$
```

But how can I make that the 4th digit is always 1?

Example:

```
0031000 true

9991999 true

9992999 false
```

Comment: `^\d{3}1\d{3}$`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex to capture two parts of number, before and after digit one:

```
^\d{3}(?:1)\d{3}$
```

Using `(?:1)` (a non-capturing group) mean you need find digit one but dont want capture this. On the final result you get only `^\d{3}` and `\d{3}$`.

Comment: `(?:1)` = `1`, the use of a non-capturing group is not justified here, and you basically copied JvdV's solution from his comment.